# How not to add delimiter after last element

Tags: python, delimiter

Im working on python code that reads and then updates lines in file and shows them in tabulate(before and after)
but when it write data back to file, delimiter ":" is added after last element and that crashes tabulate form, how can i avoid this

```
with open ('hotel.txt', 'w') as file:
    for i in list:
        for j in i:
            file.write(j+':')
        file.write('\n')
```

error:
Exception: Row has incorrect number of values, (actual) 8!=7 (expected)

Also: i cant change tabulate form because of assigment

Comment: How exactly does it crash? Please post a sample input that illustrates the issue, and a full traceback of the error as well.

Comment: `that reads` reads what file? Are you trying to update while reading the file then `'w'` is not sufficient for that operation

Answer (score 4):

It is conventional to use `str.join` when combining strings separated by delimiters:

```
with open ('hotel.txt', 'w') as file:
    for i in list:
        file.write(":".join(i))
        file.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would just use `":".join(...)` but this assumes you have a list (or other iterable) of strings. It fails if any item is not a string, but then again, so does `file.write()`. You can use a list comprehension to stringify all items:

```
file.write(":".join(str(x) for x in item)
```

In cases where writing items is more involved, istead of writing the delimiter after each item and trying to avoid writing the last one, write the delimiter *before* each item and avoid writing the *first* one.

```
with open ('hotel.txt', 'w') as file:
    for i in list:
        delim = ""
        for j in i:
            file.write(delim + j)
            delim = ":"
        file.write('\n')
```